# php variable contains string and replace

Tags: php, contains

Very new to PHP, but I have this code

```
$url =  'http://example.com/en-us/about-us';

    if ($url contains 'en-us') {
        replace 'en';
    }
```

does anyone know how I would get this to work.

Basically if the URL contains `en-us` replace the url with `en`

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `str_replace` http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)... the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) are incredibly useful, filled with detailed explanations and examples of how to use every function... learn to use them... you should really use [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) before asking other people to spend their time answering your questions

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: Als, consider replacing "/en-us/" with "/en/" in stead to prevent unwanted result with things like `example.com/en-us/pen-usability` turning into `example.com/en/penability`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$url =  'http://example.com/en-us/about-us';

if (strpos($url,'en-us') !== false) { //first we check if the url contains the string 'en-us'
    $url = str_replace('en-us', 'en', $url); //if yes, we simply replace it with en
}
```

I hope this could be some help for you

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic to check whether the string contains a specific word or not is as:

```
<?php
$word = "words";
$mystring = "this is collection of words";
 
// Test if string contains the word 
if(strpos($mystring, $word) !== false){
    echo "Word Found!";
} else{
    echo "Word Not Found!";
}
?>
```